# кодирование массива байтов в Hex при сериализация Xml

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, base64, hex

при сериализации массива байтов XmlSerializer автоматические кодирует его в base64, можно ли как-то поменять на Hex?

```
  XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(iq));
  var doc = new XmlDocument();
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  xml.Serialize(ms, this);
```

Comment: Можно в строку преобразовать `Convert.ToHexString(ms.ToArray())`. И зачем вам здесь `doc`, если никак его не используете? Какой-то несвязный код. Для чего именно xml? Что такое `this`?

Comment: @aepot код просто выдернут из программы чтобы был понятен контекст. doc дальше используется. Xml нужен для передачи данных на сервер. А теперь по теме,В классе который сериализуется есть массивы байтов, стандартная библиотека при сериализации кодирует их в base64, а мне нужно чтобы она их кодировала в Hex, возможно ли это вообще на стандартной библиотеке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать множеством разных способов. Например, так:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));

var test = new Test { Arr = new byte[] { 121, 121, 123, 124, 125 } };

using (var outStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    xml.Serialize(outStream, test);
    xml.Serialize(Console.Out, test);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

using (var inStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    var test2 = (Test)xml.Deserialize(inStream);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", test2.Arr));
}

public class Test
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public byte[]? Arr { get; set; }

    public string ArrHex
    {
        get { return Convert.ToHexString(Arr); }
        set { Arr = Convert.FromHexString(value); }
    }
}
```

Массив байтов помечаем атрибутом `[XmlIgnore]`, чтобы сериализатор его не замечал, а (де)сериализуем другое свойство с конвертацией значения.

---

Если постороннее свойство нежелательно иметь, то следует сделать дополнительный тип DTO и (де)сериализовать его.

Comment: Спасибо больше!